# Why my material is gone when importing as .fbx or .obj?

Tags: materials, export, error

So recently I made a sunglasses for my 3D character, after I finish with it I exported it as .fbx, then when I import it in, the **Glasses** material is gone and only leaving it with default **Principle BSDF**

Here is the **Glasses material** that I made :
[image: sunglasses .blend file]

then here is the **Glasses material** when I import it after being exported as .fbx :
[image: sunglasses imported]

I've tried to export and import 3 times but all the **Glasses materials** keep turning into default white like this :
[image: Glasses material]

I've tried to export it into .obj and the same thing happens, can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

A Blender material is unique to Blender. And can just be used in Blender. Neither FBX nor Obj is capable to store it. Those are general file formats. To export to Unity or Unreal for example. And you always have to recreate the materials then. When you want to keep Blender materials then you have to use a Blender file for it.

Comment: so i need to recreate it as textures? is it?

Comment: Depends where you want to export to and what kind of materials you have. Baking into a texture could be one way, indeed. But texture is just one part of a material. Obj is pretty old, and can just deal with a very primitive phong shader.